# Dropdown not working in sidebar but working in content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a grip on html and CSS and created a side bar(nav bar). One of the list in sidebar should have a drop down for sub menus. I dont find anything wrong with my code cause when i use the same code in the content div it works fine. But it doesn't work fine in side bar. Other interesting is when the window is resized to small size. The drop down works inside the collapsed navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side" >
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">CTO HIRE LOGO</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                <li>
                <a href="" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border:none;" ></a> 
                <div class = "dropdown">Profiles 
                <button class = "dropdown-toggle" type = "button" data-toggle = "dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                      </ul></div>
                <a href="" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border:none;" >Create Profile</a> 
                <a href="" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border:none;">Settings</a>
                <a href="" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border:none;">Payment</a>
                </li>

            </ul>


          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

### But the same Dropdown works fine here

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10">
  <!-- your page content -->

                        <div class = "dropdown">Profiles 
                <button class = "dropdown-toggle" type = "button" data-toggle = "dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                      </ul></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here you are using bootstrap and with Bootstrap, a navigation bar can extend or collapse, depending on the screen size. That is why, when window is resized to small size, the drop down works inside the collapsed navbar and for large screen size its working as a nav bar.

Comment: my question is totally different @poo

Comment: pls see the updated comment

Comment: Could you please provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/61g8cwLL/ @aavrug

Comment: Working fine the both dropdown in your jsfiddle.

Comment: yes it works , the problem is when the screen size is large it doesn't work and print the contents inside the drop down like list @aavrug

Comment: No, even for large screens it seems, following it's behavior.

Comment: [link](https://unsee.cc/pozenari/) See the image in this link

Comment: It's working fine, can you please provide proper fiddle so we can see actual problem. May be some of your code is overriding another code.